# Why does the server count double entries?

Tags: node.js

```
var http = require('http');
var counter = 0;
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
        counter++;
        res.write('Used: ' + counter);
        res.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

Why does the server count double entries? I open in Chrome localhost:8888 and I have "Used: 1". This is ok, but if I refresh browser or open again, then I have "Used: 3", "Used: 5", "Used: 7" etc. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you visit a url from the browser, the browser will usually send a request for [`/favicon.ico`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) as well. This could be what is causing your double counting.

If you are using google chrome, you can open the developer console (F12 or right-click -> inspect). Then click on the Network tab and refresh your page, you will see all requests being made by the browser.